# Java JUnit: The method X is ambiguous for type Y

Tags: java, testing, junit, compiler-errors, package

I had some tests working fine. Then, I moved it to a different package, and am now getting errors. Here is the code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.jgrapht.Graphs;
import org.jgrapht.WeightedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultWeightedEdge;
import org.jgrapht.graph.SimpleWeightedGraph;
import org.junit.*; 

@Test
    public void testEccentricity() {
        WeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge> g = generateSimpleCaseGraph();
        Map<String, Double> eccen = JGraphtUtilities.eccentricities(g);

        assertEquals(70, eccen.get("alpha"));
        assertEquals(80, eccen.get("l"));
        assertEquals(130, eccen.get("l-0"));
        assertEquals(100, eccen.get("l-1"));
        assertEquals(90, eccen.get("r"));
        assertEquals(120, eccen.get("r-0"));
        assertEquals(130, eccen.get("r-1"));
    }
```

The error message is this:

**The method assertEquals(Object, Object) is ambiguous for the type JGraphtUtilitiesTest**

How can I fix this? Why did this problem occur as I moved the class to a different package?

Comment: tell us how your class is declared. Looks to me as if you've inherited from JUnit3 and then tried to statically import from JUnit4.

Comment: yeah, actually, I had JUnit3 in package A, and used JUnit4 in package B, where I originally wrote these tests. Then I switched from Package B to Package A, and the problem arose. But I don't see anything in this class that would indicate JUnit 3. Where is that declared?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

The method assertEquals(Object, Object) is ambiguous for the type ...

What this error means is that you're passing a `double` and and `Double` into a method that has two different signatures: [`assertEquals(Object, Object)`](http://junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) and [`assertEquals(double, double)`](http://junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28double,%20double%29) both of which could be called, thanks to autoboxing.

To avoid the ambiguity, make sure that you either call [`assertEquals(Object, Object)`](http://junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) (by passing two Doubles) or [`assertEquals(double, double)`](http://junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28double,%20double%29) (by passing two doubles).

So, in your case, you should use:

```
assertEquals(Double.valueOf(70), eccen.get("alpha"));
```

Or:

```
assertEquals(70.0d, eccen.get("alpha").doubleValue());
```

Comment: ok, or I could just switch it to use JUnit 4 instead of JUnit 3. How do I do that?

Comment: The solution is not really to switch from one version to the other. Instead, help the compiler and remove the ambiguity as I suggested.

Comment: Anyway, shouldn't it be assertEquals(70.0d, eccen.get("alpha")); ?

Comment: but it wasn't a problem in JUnit 4, and I'd like to avoid changing a bunch of things in my code.

Comment: @mahller Not sure who you are talking to but, even if it's more correct than the OP's code, it still ambiguous if the version of JUnit has both `assertEquals(Object, Object)` and `assertEquals(double, double)` which is the case of JUnit 4.4, 4.5. But as I said, changing the version of JUnit is not the real solution, just fix the problem.

Comment: @Rosarch For this particular case, it isn't a problem in JUnit 3.8.1, it isn't a problem in JUnit 4.3, it **is** a problem in JUnit 4.4, it **is** a problem in JUnit 4.5 (but the method taking 2 doubles is deprecated), it isn't a problem in JUnit 4.6 (the method has been removed). So, make your choice, but you should fix the code.

Comment: Apparently assertEquals(object, object) has been deprecated. Use `assertEquals(null, 70.0d, eccen.get("alpha").doubleValue(), 0d);` where null can be a message (String), and the last parmaeter determines a delta... "the maximum delta between expected and actual for which both numbers are still considered equal."  I also had a similar issue, this question helped.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution to this problem is just cast the second parameter into a primitive:

```
assertEquals(70, (double)eccen.get("alpha"));
```

Ambiguity removed.

This is valid for any of the Number subclasses, for example:

```
assertEquals(70, (int)new Integer(70));
```

Would solve an ambiguity too.

However, assertEquals(double, double) is deprecated as of now and for good reasons, so I encourage you to use the method with a delta as others have suggested already.

By good reasons I mean that, given the inner representation of double numbers, two apparently equal double numbers can differ in an irrelevant infinitesimal fraction and wouldn't pass a test, but that doesn't mean that there's anything wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method

```
assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double delta)
```

Which will take into account rounding error that are hinerent to floating point (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160375/comparing-double-values-for-equality-in-java) for example). You can write

```
assertEquals(70, eccen.get("alpha"), 0.0001);
```

This mean that as long as the two values differ for less than 0.0001 they are considered to be equals. This has two advantages:

- Compares floating point values as they are supposed to
- No need to cast, as the three argument assert only applyes to doubles, not to generic Objects